# Doubt regarding the flow of charge between the primary cell and secondary cell in a potentiometer

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

In the potentiometer, if the emf of primary cell and secondary cell are not equal, then the wire connected to primary cell and secondary cell will have different potential. Suppose the emf of the secondary cell is lower, then the positive charge in the wire connected to primary cell should flow towards the secondary cell. Why this does not happen? If this happens, the law of conservation of charge will not hold true as the amount of charge leaving the battery will not be same as that entering.

Answer (score 0):

In my lab, we used a potentiometer to determine an unknown voltage (the secondary cell) under no-load conditions.  We used a uniform wire of medium resistivity which was stretched along a meter stick and connected to a known voltage (the primary cell).  The negative terminal of the unknown was connected to the negative (zero) end of the wire. The positive end of the unknown was connected to a galvanometer, which went to a slide which could be moved along the wire. The slide was  moved until there was no current though the unknown.  The voltage on the wire at that point could be calculated.  In any case, the secondary cell was connected in parallel with a section of the slide wire. Current or charge did not get lost. (The system could be calibrated using a "standard cell" in the secondary position.)